# Where to Call REST API in iOS Swift (Standard Approch)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a Continuous changeable Data List which will change too frequently. That's why I need to call the API every time when any changes happen. I know where to call but I wanted to know the efficient & standard approach.

`viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` will do my job efficiently.

P.S: I am new in iOS.